# Web Request Not Returning Anything

Tags: c#, webrequest

I'm trying to login to this website here: https://freebitco.in/
So I set up a web request like so:

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://freebitco.in");
    var postdata = "op=login&btc_address=BTCADDRESS&password=PASSWORD";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length; //1PkhThc9hCXpdvcThtwX3SzbfmTzDFxL1h:bigken <= BTC Login

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
```

The messagebox returns to me nothing though, blank. I'm not sure why this is happening so I was hoping someone could shed some light on this? I've also tried using a Web Client, and it gave me the same result. Thank you guys.

EDIT: Here's the Fiddler Raw data: http://pastebin.com/WUEvq6D5
Edit 2: Tried encoding the POST data and now it returns the login page

Updated Code:

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://freebitco.in");
    var postdata = "op=login&btc_address=ADDRESS&password=PASS";
    var encoded_data = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postdata);
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encoded_data);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Have you looked at the request/response in Wireshark or Fiddler? What response are you expecting? Do you have a valid response in any other client? (As an aside, you should dispose of the response...)

Comment: If you use this same code to connect to your own test page, does it behave as expected? That will tell you if there's something wrong with your code, or if the site you're connecting to is just not giving you what you want.

Comment: I have used fiddler to look at the request, but maybe I read something wrong if anyone could look at it again on fiddler and see if i missed something maybe?

Comment: What about the captcha requested?

Comment: There is no captcha request on login, if you look there's a "I have An Account Button"